# Restful client using ajax call

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, rest

I have created simple webpage in which user enters "URL" and the "JSON data" which needs to be sent to the rest server.

```
URL: http://localhost:8080/M2M/V1/adduser
Json Data: {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "qwer",
    "profession": "sw"
}
```

I do the following in AJAX query to send the data.

```
function sendData() {
    var mydata = document.getElementById("config_req_id").value
    var url = document.getElementById("my_url_id").value
    console.log(mydata);

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: mydata,
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            console.log(data);
            console.log(textStatus);
            alert("sucess" + data);
            //data - response from server
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            console.log(jqXHR); 
            console.log(errorThrown);
            alert("error" + textStatus);
        }
    });
```

The above request always results in an error. There is no stacktrace and I have attached what I see in Firebug. I am new to Javascript so let me know if I missed something trivial.

[chrome network console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PS1HE.png) & [firebug console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPTdc.png). In the chrome console the AJAX request does not have any reponse.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the error? Also, I'd expect that this won't work in most cases as you'll be blocked from making a cross domain request by the Same origin policy

Comment: can you check the network and see the response of your requested ajax https://gyazo.com/adc91c621b2536166124a76e4bdcbfdf

Comment: Attached the firebug screenshot. It Just says "caught exception" but no more details are available.

Comment: How to get did of cross domain request? Thanks in advance

Comment: @ramkriz F12 click network https://gyazo.com/8303b959e68ecd6ad4e9ea5628106e57

Comment: Few more observations : my web server and the UI runs on the same localhost. Iam able to successfully add a record to my webserver.(Confirmed via postman too). However in the java script it always hits the "error function". I can see the reponse under the network tab too.

Comment: Note: It works only with chrome, not with firefox. Not able to relate why this happening.

Comment: From the network console I can see that there is no response for my Ajax request. something is wrong. Any pointers?